# Get type name when deserializing to JObject

Tags: c#, json.net

Is there a way to get the $type property when using Deserialize ?  I serialize with TypeNameHandling on, but when I deserialize, I don't have the assemblies that contain the type information.  I need to use the Type name to store it in the right collection, it looks like $type is not brought over to the JObject.

Edit: If I deserialize as a JObject, I can get the $type, but if I deserialize as a class that has an object as a property, the type is null.  Not sure why its getting stripped out as the $type exists in the json.  Example below:

The class

```
public class Container {
    public object Test { get; set; }
}
```

And the deserilization code

```
var container = new Container {
    Test = new Snarfblat()
};


var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(container, 
new JsonSerializerSettings {
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
});
var deserializedContainer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container>(json);

var type = ((JObject) deserializedContainer.Test)["$type"];
// Type is null

var deserializedContainer2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);

var type2 = deserializedContainer2["Test"]["$type"];
// Type is snarfblat
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prevent Json.Net from consuming the `$type` property by setting  `MetadataPropertyHandling` to `Ignore` when you deserialize:

```
var deserializedContainer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container>(json,
    new JsonSerializerSettings {
        MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore
    });

var type = ((JObject) deserializedContainer.Test)["$type"];
// Type is Snarfblat
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VBGVue

Comment: Interesting, I am able to get the type if I deserialize as a JObject instead of a class containing an object.  See my update.